# controling audio with javascript

Tags: javascript, html

When the checkbox of this file is checked there is an audiofile with a 'metronome-click' added before the 2nd audiotrack starts. Alse there's a dropdowndow in which you can choose how many times the 2nd audiotrack should repeat. I have 2 questions: is this the best way of writing the code? And is there a possibility to 'pause' the timing and restart the audio at the same timepoint? I tried window.clearTimeout(myFunction), but it doesn't work. Here's my code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
<audio id="myAudio1">
<source src="http://u1259p183.web0080.zxcs.nl/html5musicxmlviewer/waveform-playlist-1.0.9/dist/mp3/metronome.mp3" type="audio/mpeg">
</audio>
<audio id="myAudio2">
<source src="http://u1259p183.web0080.zxcs.nl/jQuery.mmenu-master/demo/sortablemenumobile/range_items/audio_notes/10_a.mp3" type="audio/mpeg">
</audio>
</head>

<body>
<span style="font-family:arial; font-size:16px;"><b>Precount:</b></span>
<input id="precount" type="checkbox"><br><br>
<span style="font-family:arial; font-size:16px;"><b>Repeat:</b></span>
 <select>
<option id="ok1">1x</option>
<option id="ok2">2x</option>
<option id="ok3">3x</option>
</select><br><br>

<button type="button" id="play">Play</button>
<button onclick="pause()">Pause</button>

<script type="text/javascript">
function pause() {
    window.clearTimeout(myFunction);
}
</script>

<script>
var a1 = document.getElementById("myAudio1"); 
var a2 = document.getElementById("myAudio2");


function timedAudio_a() {
setTimeout(PlayThrice, 4000) 
}

function timedAudio_b() {
setTimeout(PlayOnce, 0000) 
setTimeout(PlayThrice, 4000)
}


function timedAudio1() {
setTimeout(PlayThrice, 0000) 
setTimeout(PlayThrice, 4000) 
}

function timedAudio2() {
setTimeout(PlayOnce, 0000) 
setTimeout(PlayThrice, 4000)
setTimeout(PlayThrice, 8000)
}

function timedAudio3() {
setTimeout(PlayOnce, 0000) 
setTimeout(PlayThrice, 4000)
setTimeout(PlayThrice, 8000)
setTimeout(PlayThrice, 12000)
}

function timedAudio4() {
setTimeout(PlayThrice, 0000)
setTimeout(PlayThrice, 4000)
setTimeout(PlayThrice, 8000)
}

function PlayOnce() {
a1. play(); 
}
function PlayThrice() {
a2. play(); 
}
</script>

<script>

document.getElementById("play").addEventListener("click", myFunction);

function myFunction() {

if ((document.getElementById("precount").checked==true) &&        (document.getElementById("ok1").selected==true)) {
timedAudio_b();
} 

else if ((document.getElementById("precount").checked==false) &&   (document.getElementById("ok1").selected==true)) {
timedAudio_a();
} 

else if ((document.getElementById("precount").checked==true) &&   (document.getElementById("ok2").selected==true)) {
timedAudio2();
} 

else if ((document.getElementById("precount").checked==false) &&   (document.getElementById("ok2").selected==true)) {
timedAudio1();
} 

else if ((document.getElementById("precount").checked==false) &&   (document.getElementById("ok3").selected==true)) {
timedAudio4();
} 

else if ((document.getElementById("precount").checked==true) &&   (document.getElementById("ok3").selected==true)) {
timedAudio3();
} 

else {
timedAudio1(); 
}
}
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Have you looked into the method functions that `a1` would have as an `AudioElement`? Take a look at [Using HTML5 audio and video](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/HTML/Using_HTML5_audio_and_video).  There should be a `.pause()` method.

Comment: thanks, but no, I have to translate this script into a more sophisticated script, so I really need javascript.

Comment: That **is** JavaScript.  You're controlling your `<audio>` through the DOM API which is JavaScript.